# Architectural Design Question W/ Streaming and Live Dashboard

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, plotly-dash

I am developing a dashboard displaying the sentiment of all tweets in real-time. I have a Python twitter streamer using tweepy that is streaming the tweets via AWS Kinesis to an AWS databricks environment using a pyspark notebook that is parsing the raw JSON into a tweet object (id, timestamp, and the text of the tweet), constructing the model, and then running the tweet through the model and getting its sentiment (-1, 0, and 1) which is then tacked on to that individual tweet object (so now the tweet object looks like: id, timestamp, the text of the tweet, sentiment). Currently, I am sending these individual tweet objects to a dynamodb table which will be queried by my Display.py so the live dashboard can be populated with data.

I'm coming to the realization that dynamodb may cap out at a certain point with all these reads/writes and was wondering if there may be a better way to store this stream of tweets other than dynamodb? I intended to erase the contents in the table maybe every hour to save on space, but idk how soon dynamodb will just cap out. Is there a better way to maybe approach this application than the way I am currently?

Maybe instead of dynamodb, stream the analyzed tweets to my local machine to something like SQLlite? I intend to host the Dispaly.py via heroku since it will be using Dash/Plotly and is similar to Flask.

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains a number of separate parts, which I'll try to address separately.

> I'm coming to the realization that dynamodb may cap out at a certain point with all these reads/writes

There are two ways to interpret this: that you're worried it will "cap out" in terms of scale (not being able to handle the load) or in cost.

Regarding scale, Amazon themselves use DynamoDB to power large parts of their services, and several companies use it for *absolutely huge* problems. In Prime Day 2019, DynamoDB tables of Amazon services [peaked at 45.4 million requests ***per second***](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-prime-day-2019-powered-by-aws/). It's *extremely, extremely unlikey* that you'll come anywhere close to reaching the limit of what DynamoDB can handle.

Naturally, you'd have to model your data well to not run into trouble in lower scales. A good read of the [Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html) part of the docs will get you a long way.

Regarding cost, this is definitely a factor that you must handle. If you're dealing with Twitter Firehose data, this can get expensive very quickly. I'd recommend you make a cost estimate, no matter which tech you choose.

> I intended to erase the contents in the table maybe every hour to save on space, but idk how soon dynamodb will just cap out

Space is very unlikely to be the most relevant factor here either in performance or cost. Given you design your primary keys correctly (again, check the Best Practices doc), the influence of the entire table size in queries is close to zero, even if you have billions of tweets.

For cost, expiring older records will save *some* money, but not much compared to the cost to write and read them in the first place.

If you decide it's still a good idea to expire older items, DynamoDB can manage this for you with the [TTL (Time To Live)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-before-you-start.html) feature.

> Maybe instead of dynamodb, stream the analyzed tweets to my local machine to something like SQLlite

This sounds like a *Very, Very Bad Idea*. Plus, if you plan to host your app server ("Display.py") in the cloud (Heroku or elsewhere), how would it communicate with a local database on your machine? Even if you get *that* sorted out, you'd still be managing a large database _in your local machines.

> I intend to host the Dispaly.py via heroku since it will be using Dash/Plotly and is similar to Flask

Most Platform-as-a-Service solutions (Heroku, App Engine, etc) would be fine.

> Is there a better way to maybe approach this application than the way I am currently?

Your current approach, which basically consists of Twitter > Kinesis > Spark > DynamoDB > Web visualization doesn't sound off. Now, for one to say this is the "better" way, more information would be needed (what's your budget? How many tweets are we talking about? How many accesses are we talking about?).

Comment: On average there are about 500million tweets a day, so I Intend to store 1% of that. So in theory, the database can be holding up to 5million tweets sorted by most recent via their timestamp.  I am collecting all tweets so the user can be able to query a topic and get a graph of that topic sentiment, so the database will be accessed only when the user tries to look up a topic's sentiment. By default, the graph will be plotting the sentiment of all tweets that get stored in the database by most recent.

Comment: Yeah after thinking about it, the local database idea is pretty bad. I only really thought of that because of the implementation of an application similar to mine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6ixFSxZAX0&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfsGImWNt1eUEveHOepkjqt&index=10

Comment: Do you plan to allow the user to query by any arbitrary topic or will you precalculate the topics? If you can, try to precalculate sentiment by topic in a time-series manner (say, average sentiment for the topic every five minutes). Storing the full text and having the graph generation scan through millions of tweets to generate that graph is going to be slow and expensive.